# nginx: Exclude subdomains from being SSL-encrypted

Tags: nginx

Can you exclude all other subdomains from being encrypted if the main site url is using SSL?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name .example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ## ssl stuff

    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;   
}
```

Comment: Sure - access it as `http`, not `https`.

Comment: They get forced back to https

Comment: None of the nginx config you've shared would do that. Somewhere else you've got something that's listening to port 80 and issuing a redirect. Find it and tweak it.

Comment: I have updated answer. I found other directives being included before the one I posted earlier.

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation on [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html). It would be easier to list the subdomains, so long as it's a small set, otherwise perhaps a regular expression. If you use a wildcard server and a server for the main domain, the main domain server will be used when it can as it's more specific than the wildcard.

Comment: They have a lot of subdomains.  In the port 80 listening would it fix the issue if instead I was redirected just by `example.com` instead of `.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Define a more specific server, that will be used in place of the one you have.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain1.example.com; # add others if you like
  root /home/forge/example.com/public/subdomain; # check this
  index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

As ceejay noted in comments there's no redirect included in the config you included, so something else is going on.

To round it up, the more specific `server_name` gets served and therefore no `301` redirect is made. Taken from [here][1].

> 1. exact name
> 2. longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “*.example.org”
> 3. longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
> 4. first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)

Comment: what if these subdomain are not located on same server would you just return a 301 redirect to http?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonably way to do it, define a server block and put a 301 in there.

Comment: I have updated my question I found more directive that get loaded before.  I am unsure how to tweak them to accomplish what I need.